# Using the dateformatter in matplotlib to show only months and year

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

This is probably quite basic but after days of searching, I'm having little luck.

So, this is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(master.index, master["UPR"], 'r')
ax1.plot(master.index, master["LWR"], 'r')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(master.index, master["AVG"])

plt.show()
```

'master' is a pandas DataFrame, with the index being the date and UPR,LWR and AVG are just columns I have calculated to plot.

When plotted, it looks like this:
[image]

That massive smudge on the x-axis is actually all the dates compacted together.

Now I've ready the other articles on here but they've been of little help, mostly due to the way my graph is set up.

Please help.

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve]. I have the suspicion that your index is strings instead of dates, but how would anyone know.

Comment: Ok i converted it to datetime but now it's just in exponential format. I removed the todatetime earlier as I wasn't sure if it was helping.

Comment: I guess that is a totally different issue. Again, see [mcve].